# Android AlarmManager and IntentService - Marshallow and above

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow, intentservice, android-7.0-nougat

How to make an AlarmManager to work with an IntentService which will be repeated every 5 seconds?
Is there any possibility to "bypass" the 1/15 min barrier (idle/doze mode)? It has to work all time (even if app is closed).

**EDIT:**
Here I have code of AlarmReceiver which extends from WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, VidService.class);
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5000, alarmIntent);
    } else {
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, alarmIntent);
        } else {
            alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, alarmIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And there is code of my IntentService.

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    checkIncommingCall();
    AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Unfortunately, my service "worked" only once. I tested on Android 7.0 so my question - Is setExactAndAllowWhileIdle repetitive?

Comment: I dont know why you accepted that answer. It doesn't answer your question at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private static void startbyalarm(Context ctx, boolean wakeup, long nexttime) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(BRPing.INTENT_FILTER);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, intentalarm, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            am.set(wakeup?AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP:, nexttime, pi);
        } else {
            if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
            } else {
                am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
            }
        }
    }
```

Nonetheless, I highly recomment do not wakeup the devices each 5 seconds!
This really consumes battery!

**EDIT**

```
public class BRPing extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String INTENT_FILTER = "Some.Intent.Name.BRPing";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(ctx.getPackageName(),
                YourService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(ctx, intent.setComponent(comp));
    }

}
```

manifest.xml:

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".BRPing"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Some.Intent.Name.BRPing" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I know that it really consumes battery. Maybe there is other option to have a service working and checking every 5sec?

Comment: @Ace this case is the most useful. But even alarmmanager consumes the battery.

Comment: Can you tell me what means "BRPing.INTENT_FILTER"? Is BRPing your class or what? Secondly where do you declare "intentalarm" variable?

Comment: intentalarm is some constant (random) integer to cancel alarm later.

Comment: @Ace. Omg, that's so easy. Recharge the alarmmanager in `onDestroy()` method of the service.

Answer (score 0):

> Is setExactAndAllowWhileIdle repetitive?

No it is not. If you need repetition, you have to schedule a new alarm at the moment the current one fires.

> How to make an AlarmManager to work with an IntentService which will be repeated every 5 seconds?

That is not possible because when doze is active it requires at least 15 minutes between two alarms.

> Is there any possibility to "bypass" the 1/15 min barrier (idle/doze mode)? It has to work all time (even if app is closed).

No, there is not.